# How do I programmatically create an order without deleting a profile?

Tags: commerce

I followed [Orders](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/orders) to write the following code.

```php
$order = \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\Order::create([
  'type' => 'custom_order_type',
  'state' => 'draft',
  'mail' => 'user@example.com',
  'uid' => 1,
  'ip_address' => '127.0.0.1',
  'order_number' => '6',
  'billing_profile' => $profile,
  'store_id' => $store->id(),
  'order_items' => [$order_item],
  'placed' => time(),
]);
```

`$profile` is a user profile.

I then programmatically change the order status to *place* with `$order->getState()->applyTransitionById('place');`.

The order is placed and everything looks fine, except that the user addressbook becomes empty. I think I miss a step.

Is there a way to preserve the addressbook while placing the order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The profile is not being deleted - it's just becoming "owned" by the order. This occurs in `Order::preSave()` where the profile uid is set to 0. This ensures that a customer will not be able to use the addressbook interface to edit a profile referenced by an order. For more background on how the addressbook in Commerce 2.x works with respect to profile copying, please see may article:

https://www.centarro.io/blog/understanding-drupal-commerce-2x-address-book

The solution is for you to create a copy of the profile yourself, set its uid to 0, and reference that profile from your order instead of the original one.

Comment: Thank you, this solves my issue